# -Holographic Displays API- How to remove holograms near a player

Tags: bukkit

I am making a plugin. That when a command is typed. It removes the nearest Holograms to the sender/player. Now, the things I have tried are to remove the Invisible armor stands in a radius of 10 blocks. I also tried to see if there is a method to get the nearest holograms, but I had no luck. If there is any way to point to what I need to do, that would be helpful. I am not asking for code, just for what I need to look under, say a specific class etc.

Thanks, seb.

Trying to remove armor stands:

```
for(Entity en : player.getNearbyEntities(10, 10, 10)) {
            if(en instanceof ArmorStand) {
                en.remove();
            }
}
```

My Question: **Where should I look to find a way to remove nearby Holograms to the player? If you can provide code, not needed though.**

Comment: Can I please know why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Loop through all existing holograms registered to your plugin
for (Hologram hologram : HologramsAPI.getHolograms(plugin)) {
    Location playerLoc   = player.getLocation();
    Location hologramLoc = hologram.getLocation();

    //Check if the distance between the locations are less than 10
    //and deletes the hologram if true
    if (playerLoc.distance(hologramLoc) < 10) {
        hologram.delete();
    }
}
```

This Holographic Displays API has a [hologram delete method](https://github.com/filoghost/HolographicDisplays/blob/master/HolographicDisplays/API/com/gmail/filoghost/holographicdisplays/api/Hologram.java#L196).

https://github.com/filoghost/HolographicDisplays/wiki